# Dialog is not opening after some time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI dialog, as soon as page is reloaded it works fine, but if I have awaited for some time, or doesn't do any action, then I clicked again on button to open that dialog, then it is giving error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
>   deleteNode
>   (anonymous function)

My code sample is as following:

```
function deleteNode(d) {
    $("#deleteNodeDialog").dialog({
        /*My delete node functionality here*/
    });
}
```

Comment: It looks like you initialize dialog every time `deleteNode` is called. What is the purpose of this behaviour?

Comment: how do you close the dialog?, may be your close function remove some html like the #deleteNodeDialog element.

Comment: What is `d`..? What about the rest of the code..? Can you replicate the issue in an online demo..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having more information, I would try to just "open" the dialog with your `deleteNode` function rather than re-initializing it every time.

```
$("#deleteNodeDialog").dialog({
        /*My delete node functionality here*/
    });
```

Then

```
function deleteNode(d) {
     $("#deleteNodeDialog").dialog("open");
}
```

This way you aren't recreating it when it isn't necessary.. UNLESS there is more going on inside the function we don't know about yet that makes it necessary.